# RCloud URL and Google Analytics Error

Tags: google-analytics, rcloud

So RCloud applications produce a URL with a query string. `https://rcloud.social/shared.R/rcloud.shiny/shiny.html?notebook=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.`

But when I try to use it to track metrics via Google Analytics it gets rejected. Is there a way to change the URL to exclude the query or adjust settings in GA to accept the URL?

[image]